# Where Should I Store my Temp application data for different OS Versions?

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, temp

I have an application that run on diffident OS version like(`win XP,win 7,win 8`).
I have a `.sdf` data base with read-only access,i used `Environment.SpecialFolder.Templates` for temp path.

```
Temp Path= Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Templates)
```

It's work fine on `win 7` ,but return error(`permission denied`) on `win XP` and `win 8`.

So i want to ask "What’s the recommended location for Application database in different Os version ?"
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if you use Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is user specific

```
Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData
```

Else if the data is shared by all users of the application

```
Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData
```